# jquery add data to asp.net table using after function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm going to implement JQuery infinite scroll in my ASP.NET web app, I use following jquery funcyion (taken from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETInfiniteLoading-16f5bdb8):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       function lastPostFunc() {
           $('#divPostsLoader').html('<img src="images/bigLoader.gif">');

           //send a query to server side to present new content
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Default.aspx/Foo",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {

                   if (data != "") {
                       $('.divLoadData:last').after(data.d);
                   }
                   $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
               }

           })
       };
```

divLoadData is a div which will receive data (in HTML format), but I want to append data to an asp.net table, how can I append data? I should use after function? also how should I generate my HTML for appending to this server-side table control, currently data is created using the following code (in the webmethod function):

```
  foreach (DataRowView myDataRow in dv)
            {
                getPostsText.AppendFormat("<p>author: {0}</br>", myDataRow["author"]);
                getPostsText.AppendFormat("genre: {0}</br>", myDataRow["genre"]);
                getPostsText.AppendFormat("price: {0}</br>", myDataRow["price"]);
                getPostsText.AppendFormat("publish date: {0}</br>", myDataRow["publish_date"]);
                getPostsText.AppendFormat("description: {0}</br></p>", myDataRow["description"]);
            }
            getPostsText.AppendFormat("<div style='height:15px;'></div>");
```

and finally `getPostsText` is sent to JQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .after() function in jQuery to append some content after another element.

So instead of

```
$("servers").append( ... );
```

you would use

```
$("#" + id + ).closest( "tr" ).after( ... );
```

or you could also use

```
$( ... ).insertAfter( $("#" + id ).closest( "tr" ) );
```

which is essentially equivalent.

See http://api.jquery.com/after/ for full details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to moveout the function outside of `doc ready`:

```
function lastPostFunc() {
       $('#divPostsLoader').html('<img src="images/bigLoader.gif">');
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/Foo",
           data: {},
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
               if (data != "") {
                   $('#divDynamicData').append(data.d);
               }
               $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
           }
       });
   }


$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).scrollHeight - $(window).height()) {
         lastPostFunc();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: because you have to call it in scroll and functions Either should be initialized in the docready or call it this way as in the answer.

Comment: I'm going to use a div as in the sample, but no data is added to my div, and I see only my gif image for some moments, then nothing is added to my page, what is going wrong?

Comment: yes it is working, I can view my data using alert(data.d), but it seems that $('.divLoadData').last().after(data.d); doesn't work, I used this: document.getElementById('divDynamicData').innerHTML += data.d;, and it worked, is it okay? or I can do it better?

Comment: yup with `.append()` you can try out this one `$('#divDynamicData').append(data.d);`